# react native- Loading dependency graph -

Tags: react-native

create react native app using

`sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app`

`create-react-native-app my-appAfter`

After successfully creating an app in react,
when `start NPM`  it's stuck on Loading dependency graph 
try all possible aspect but not start NPM graph

and `index.andorid.js` is also not present in an android folder

Comment: check where there is package.json in the same directory.
navigate to `my-appAfter` folder and then press npm start as per docs
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: yes `package.jason` in the same directory,  do it same as per git doc same issue

Comment: Can you share repo ?